# Why item discriminations are missing in IRT GRM, estimated as a part of the Structural Equation Model?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, item-response-theory, lavaan

I have run a Structural Equation Model that has four latent constructs (FI, SC, EM and RB) in R. All of the factors are continuous. Meanwhile, indicators are all ordered categorical variables measured on different scales.  There are from 5 to 25 indicator variables per factor.

I have estimated the model using a function *sem* from *lavaan* package, stating that the manifest variables are ordered.

I presume that the measurement model would be IRT GRM for each of the constructs. Therefore, in the output for the measurement model I expected to see cutpoints (a.k.a. thresholds, item difficulties or extremities) and item discriminations for each of the indicators.

However, the output from the measurement model provides me with thresholds only (i.e. no discriminations).

Also, the complete output shows ‘intercepts’ for both indicators and latent constructs, and they are all, without exception, set to zero. I am not sure what is the interpretation of these ‘intercepts’ and why they are set to zero.  I am not even certain whether they come from the measurement or from the structural model.

I am mostly concerned with the absence of discriminations for the indicators, as when I run the measurement model separately from the structural model  using function *grm* from *ltm* package I receive both item extremities and discriminations. Moreover, constraining the extremities to the same value within the construct provides worse fit.  Needless to say that the cutpoints provided by *sem* and by *grm* are different in my case.

I will be grateful for any help, including suggestions of readings that can make the picture clearer.

I could not find answers for my questions in either of the articles for ltm and lavaan (Rizopoulos, 2006 and Rosseel, 2012, respectively).

*Rizopolous, D., 2006. Ltm: An R Package for Latent Variable Modeling and Item Response Theory Analyses. Journal of Statistical Software, Vol.17(5).*

*Rosseel, Y., 2012. Lavaan: An R Package for Structural Equation Modeling. Journal of Statistical Software, Vol.48(2).*

I have provided the code that I used below. I will be extremely grateful if anyone can point out where about in the code I specified the equality restriction on the discriminations and set them to zeros, or whether it is imposed by default in sem, or by construction of the model.

```
    library(lavaan)
FC.Model<- ' 
#Factor Extraction:
             FI =~ EPACTI00 + EPGAME00 + EPTAIM00 + EPLOOK00

             SC =~ FPSDPF00 + FPSDHU00 + FPSDKY00   + FPSDVH00

             EM =~ FCHWKM00 + FCSINT00 + FCSCWA00 + FCSCBE00 + FCATQL00

             RB =~ FCSMOK00 + FCECIG00 + FCALCN00 +
                   FCCANO00 + FCOTDR00 + FCGAMA00 + FCGMBL00 + FCGAEM00 +
                   FCGAMJ00 + FCPCKP00  + FCCYBO00 + FCRUDE00 + FCSTOL00 +
                   FCSPRY00 + FCDAMG00 + FCKNIF00 + FCROBH00 + FCHITT00 + 
                   FCWEPN00 + FCSTLN00 + FCCAUT00   + FCARES00 + FCGANG00 +
                   FCHACK00 + FCCONP0A
# Regressions:
            SC ~ FI
            EM ~ FI
            RB ~ FI
#Covariances:
            SC~~EM
            EM~~RB
            RB~~SC
'

fit<-sem(model=FC.Model,
         data=mcs_c,ordered = c("EPACTI00","EPGAME00","EPTAIM00","EPLOOK00",
                                "FPSDPF00","FPSDHU00","FPSDKY00","FPSDVH00",
                                "FCHWKM00","FCSINT00","FCSCWA00","FCSCBE00","FCATQL00",
                                "FCSMOK00","FCECIG00","FCALCN00",
                                "FCCANO00","FCOTDR00","FCGAMA00","FCGMBL00","FCGAEM00",
                                "FCGAMJ00","FCPCKP00","FCCYBO00","FCRUDE00","FCSTOL00",
                                "FCSPRY00","FCDAMG00","FCKNIF00","FCROBH00","FCHITT00",
                                "FCWEPN00","FCSTLN00","FCCAUT00","FCARES00","FCGANG00",
                                "FCHACK00","FCCONP0A")) 

summary(fit, fit.measures= TRUE, standardized= TRUE)
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think `lavaan` fits linear SEM, so you didn't fit a graded response model at all. You may have told the package the indicators are ordinal, and thus it used a weighted least squares estimator. However, that estimator is acceptable if (and I could be wrong on this description) the items are censored representations of multivariate normal latent variables. That doesn't change the fact that you're still fundamentally fitting a linear SEM - unless I'm totally wrong about `lavaan`'s capabilities.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @WeiwenNg. I came across the website that supports *lavaan*. Here is a link to the section where categorical exogenous and endogenous variables are discussed [link](http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/cat.html). What I did not pay attention to is that one needs to declare as ordinal only **endogenous** ordered variables.  The method used in the latter scenario is DWLS. I re-ran my analysis without declaring 'ordered', as my ordered indicators are exogenous to the model (Is that right?). And the method now is Maximum Likelihood. So, I guess it works now. Thanks again!

Comment: I still do not see the output that I need in R (i.e. item extremities and discriminations). I will probably try to estimate and save factor scores using 'grm' from 'ltm' and then will run the structural model using 'sem' in 'lavaan'.

Comment: Like I said, I believe you don't see the item discriminations and difficulty parameters because you did not fit a graded response model. You fit a linear SEM.

Comment: I think there is a support forum for lavaan which is likely to hold more specialist expertise.

Comment: thank you, @mdewey. I have found the lavaan forum on Google groups [link](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/lavaan).